# ssue with workspace setup in RAD 8.5 using websphere application server 6.1

Tags: ibm-rad

I am facing difficulty in setting up a workspace in IBM RAD 8.5, which I've created in RAD 7.0. I am getting below error while launching my application. can anyone suggest how to resolve this.

```
---------------------------------------ERROR----------------------------------------------


Annotation processing failed with the following error: com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationException: Annotation processing failed for class:  COM/ibm/db2os390/sqlj/custom/DB2SQLJCustomizer.class
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.getAnnotationData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:461)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.annotations.AnnotationConfigReader.populateModuleData(AnnotationConfigReader.java:246)
at com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataOrchestrator.getModuleData(MetaDataOrchestrator.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.annotations.collector.WASAnnotationCollector.getMDO(WASAnnotationCollector.java:215)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.annotations.collector.WASAnnotationCollector.collect(WASAnnotationCollector.java:108)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.getClassDataObjects(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:419)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.getWARCDOs(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:377)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:218)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexDataBuilder.getWSData(ServiceIndexDataBuilder.java:48)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTaskImpl.listWebServices(ServiceIndexServerTaskImpl.java:142)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTaskImpl.listWebServices(ServiceIndexServerTaskImpl.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTask.performTask(ServiceIndexServerTask.java:163)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:262)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in db2 driver:

> Annotation processing failed for class:
>   COM/ibm/db2os390/sqlj/custom/DB2SQLJCustomizer.class
>
> For a very brief amount of time, a db2jcc.jar was shipped on zOS where
>   the 'DB2SQLJCustomizer.class' it contained was corrupt.  This has
>   since been corrected by IBM.  However, if a user still has a copy of
>   this corrupt class contained in the db2jcc.jar, and the user places
>   this jar in their application, every class in that jar will be scanned
>   for annotations when the application is started.  When the
>   'DB2SQLJCustomizer.class' is scanned, the 'AnnotationsException' will
>   be thrown.

Check this page for [detailed description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK69454)

Looks like you have driver in your application libraries. It would be better not to include that jar in the application, but to define datasource on the server. It would not be scanned for annotations then.